# How do you use python to scrape text from a list of urls in a csv file and export it to another csv file?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, url, beautifulsoup

I am new to python and beautifulsoup and I am trying to use it to scrape text data from a list of multiple urls located in a csv file by using a loop to then export the url and text into another csv file. The loop locates the url from list1.csv, scrapes the text data and places it in list2.csv with the url and text data.
My code below only seems to do the first two urls in my list of 10.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
import csv

with open("list1.csv", "r") as f_urls, open("list2.csv", "w", newline="") as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['url', 'text'])

    for url in f_urls:
        url = url.strip()
        html = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "html.parser")
        text = soup.get_text()
        csv_output.writerow([url, text])
```

I tried to clean up the text data by using the code below to only get the content but it resulted in a blank output.

```
results = soup.find_all('p')
str_cells = str(results)
cleantext = BeautifulSoup(str_cells, "lxml").get_text()
```